# Проектирование кода: использование return в switch

Tags: java, code-style

Какой код с точки зрения проектирования более правильный

Такой:

```
public List<String> getStringList(int expression){
  List<String> list;

  switch(expression){
   case 1:
     list = getList1();
     break;
   case 2:
     list = getList2();
     break;
   ...
  }
  return list;
}
```

Или такой:

```
public List<String> getStringList(int expression){
  switch(expression){
   case 1:
     return getList1();
   case 2:
     return getList2();
   ...
  }
}
```

В данный момент мы никак не изменяем и не предопалагаем, что нам нужно изменять список `list` в функции `getStringList`.

Хотелось бы прочитать обоснованный ответ в пользу того или иного варианта.

В первом случае у нас одна точка выхода их функции, в `switch` мы только присваиваем переменную, которую возвращаем, а во втором случае у нас получается несколько точек выхода.

Comment: в чем принципиальное отличие этих кусков?

Comment: в том, что в первом случае у нас одна точка выхода их функции, в switch мы только присваиваем переменную, которую возвращаем, а во втором случае у нас получается несколько точек выхода

Comment: Стоит добавить это непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Сама тема холливарная: все советуют по разному.

Comment: Хм, а в литературе это случаем не встречали? Я что-то не могу припомнить, знаю только, что SonarQube считает функцию сложной, если в ней несколько раз return употребить в одной функции

Comment: Во втором вариант компилятор будет ругаться на `unreachable statement` (то есть на `break`)

Comment: Косяк, да, поправил

Comment: вообще-то второй вариант не будет работать.

с точки зрения проектирования вы путаете проектирование в любом случае Вы нарушаете принцип OCP.
Ну это очень глобальный ответ. Что вы хотите сделать вообще сложно понять.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793)

Comment: @Rasul, а в чем заключается нарушение?

Comment: @Grundy, но он же на английском :)

Comment: @iRumba, поэтому я и не флагнул как дубликат :-)

Comment: @Grundy это похоже на какой-то фабрику Ну вообще-то я сказал я глобальное ответил. Принцип открытости/закрытости (Open/Closed) 
OCP.  он хочет сделать алгоритмический рефакторинг .)

Comment: Не стоит заморачиваться на такие вопросы, это из ряда как писать в `for` - `...; i++` или же `...; ++i`.  
Всё зависит от конкретного случая, как удобнее будет, как вам больше нравится и т.п. В книжках часто пишут про некий идеальный код в вакууме, да, я тоже неоднократно читал, например, что в методе нужно чтобы был 1 `return`. На практике же, где-то будет костыль, который уводит код от идеальности и придется впихнуть два или три `return`. Главное чтобы код был читабельным, эффективным и таким, чтобы если понадобилось добавить новую фичу - вы смогли это сделать не перепиливая весь проект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В языках с RAII или try/finally нет никакого правила, по которому предпочтительнее единственная точка возврата из функции. Поэтому писать надо так, как легче читать, никакого другого правила тут нет.

В вашем случае, как мне кажется, введение дополнительной переменной служит только цели единственной точки возврата в функции, так что я бы предпочёл более короткий вариант с `return` из середины `switch`. Введение дополнительной переменной заставляет читателя помнить о результате до конца `switch`'а, и держать наличие его в голове, в то время как ранний `return` позволяет сразу отбросить этот случай.

Но это, снова-таки, вопрос личных *литературных* предпочтений. Пишите, как вам кажется лучше.